# get list from a class to fill taxtbox in other class by linq

Tags: linq

how to get just special 2 attributes from a table to other table( and placement in related textbox) by LINQ??

```
public string srcht(ACTIVITIES sn)
    {
        db db = new db();
        var q = (from i in db.costumers.Where(i => i.id== sn.id)select i.name).ToList();
       return q.Single(); 
   }
public string srcht(ACTIVITIES sn)
    {
        db db = new db();
        var q = (from i in db.costumers.Where(i => i.id== sn.id)select i.family).ToList();
        return q.Single(); 
   }
```

i did linq twice to fill 2 textboxes by name and family in other table.  can i do it by one LINQ?

Comment: Question is not clear. I see two copies of the same function and no way to understand what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

So you have an `Activity` in sn, and you want the `Name` and the `Family` of all `Customers` that have an `Id` equal to `sn.Id`.

```
var result = db.Customers.Where(customer => customer.Id == sn.Id)
    .Select(customer => new
    {
        Name = customer.Name,
        Family = customer.Family,
    });
```

In words: in the database, from the table of Customers, keep only those Customers that have a value for property Id that equals the value of sn.Id. From the remaining Customers select the values of Name and Family.

If you expect that there will only be at utmost one such customer (so if Id is the primary key), just add:

```
.FirstOrDefault();
```

If you think there will be several of these customers, add:

```
.ToList();
```

The result will be an object, or a list of objects of some anonymous type with two properties: Name and Family.

If you want to mix the Name and the Family in one sequence of strings, which I doubt, consider to put the Name and the Family in an array. Result is sequence of arrays of strings. To make it one array of Strings, use SelectMany:

```
var result = db.Customers
    .Where(customer => customer.Id == sn.Id)
    .Select(customer => new string[]
    {
        customer.Name,
        customer.Family,
    })
    .SelectMany(customer => customer);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Dear friend, actually i used this method to put this "name" and "family" in to separate textboxes in activities form. you know, when i typed id, related name and family appear in related textboxes.